# Sufficient criteria to know if a complex measure is the zero measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to see if the following condition is enough to determine if a complex measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the zero measure, however I dont see a clear way to handle the question. Suppose that $\int p\mathop{}\!d \mu=0$ for any complex polynomial $p$, can we say that $\mu$ is the zero measure? Some help will be appreciated.

---

An idea could be to see if the integral of any simple function is zero knowing that the integral of any polynomial is zero, however it doesn't seem true that a simple function is the limit of a sequence of polynomials.

Comment: Could you approximate indicator functions with the polynomials?

Comment: The result is not true in general. Using two different solutions $\nu$ and $\eta$ to the [Hamburger problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_moment_problem#Uniqueness_of_solutions)  you can construct a measure $\mu=\nu-\eta$ such that $\mu(p)=0$ for all polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the measure $\mu$ has compact support (or rather its variation $|\mu|$ has compact support), then the answer should be in the positive as the Stone-Weierstrass would show.

The result in general is not true. This is related to the moment problem in probability (Stieltjes moment problem in the $(0,\infty)$, Hamburger moment problem for $\mathbb{R}$)

Here is a counterexample by Heyde:

Consider the lognormal distribution whose density is
$$f_0(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{x}\exp(-\frac12 \log^2x)\mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}(x)$$

for $|a|<1$ let
$$f_a(x)=f_0(x)\big(1+a\sin(2\pi\log x)\big)$$

It is not difficult to check that
$$\int^\infty_0 f_0(x)x^n \sin(2\pi\log x)\,dx=0,\qquad n=0,1,\ldots$$

So, the measure $\mu(dx)=(f_0(x)-f_a(x))\,dx$ is not $0$ and $\mu(p)=0$  for any polynomial.

There are other nice counterexamples. The book of counterexamples in Probability by Stoyan is a good place to see more of them.